# Why append works on empty list?

Tags: python, list, matrix

```
matrix = [[1, 2], [3,4], [5,6], [7,8]]
transpose = []

for i in range(2):

    a=[]
    print (a)

    transpose.append(a)

    for row in matrix:

         a.append(row[i])
print (transpose)
```

before `transpose.append(a)` is executed, list a is emptied by a = []
because at the end all the numbers are printed, it should not print empty

Comment: Why would `append` *not* work on an empty list?

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't be empty?

Comment: Aqui  menciona eso , lo llaman  Reinitializing the list 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-clear-a-list-in-python/

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing as it is currently written. Try [StackOverflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) instead.

Comment: if you don't want to append an empty list then just ```if len(x) != 0: your_list.append(x)```

Comment: Assumption: 1) you thought you where adding empty lists to transpose list, and 2) you were adding elements, row[i],  to a list.   Your surprise is the transpose has the row elements.  This is because a better what of thinking about it is you where adding references to objects to transpose.  These objects where initially empty.  You later updated these objects by appending row[i] to these objects.  The objects are only update (i.e. mutated), so transpose still has the same objects. Just that now the object are no longer empty.

Answer (score 0):

*Append works on empty lists because in the python, the append() method appends an element to the end of the list, regardless of it being empty or not.*